# Apache Server on Ubuntu 18.04 serves site to elastic IP but not to domain ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, apache-http-server, website

I created an Apache2 web server on an ec2 Ubuntu 18.04 instance on AWS. I have a domain purchased from a third party register (Porkbun) that I wish to connect to my ec2 instance. I have taken the NS from AWS Route 5S and copied them over to Porkbun, so they should be pointed to AWS Route 5S. On Route 5S I have created A records for `*<domain_name>`, `www<domain_name>` and `@<domain_name>` to the elastic IP of my ec2 instance. When using `nslookup <domain_name>` it returns the elastic IP.

When I put the elastic IP in the web browser it returns the apache default page with no issue when trying `http://<domain_name>` it returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. My inbound/outbound rules on AWS allow http/https from anywhere with the only restriction is on SSH to my personal private IP address. I even disabled `ufw` to see if that was causing an issue - with the same result.

When using a network sniffer I can see the hits when refreshing the browser on the `http:<elastic_IP>`, but nothing when I browse `http:<domain_name>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Virtual host for http traffic

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName <domain_name>
    ServerAlias www.<domain_name>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/<domain_name>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory />
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: There might be a problem with your virtual host file. Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

I used Certbot to create an SSL certificate for `<domain_name>` and after the successful creation of the certificate accessing the domain worked! When I was attempting to connect to my domain I was specifically trying `http://<domain_name>` in my browser since I had not created a Virtual Host for 443 traffic. I am guessing Apache was forwarding traffic to the https site - which would explain why I was receiving ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when attempting to access the content.